# confine snowflake warehouse usage on user level

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, privileges, warehouse

A user **ABC** has access to role **product_role**

There are 2 warehouses accessible using the **product_role**

say for eg: **whs1** and **whs2**

Is there any way that we can confine user privileges that **ABC** can use only **whs1** but not **whs2** while using the role **product_role**

Comment: No, since Snowflake uses RBAC, access privileges are assigned to roles, which are in turn assigned to users.

Comment: create another role `product_role_for_the_user_who_works_all_the_time...` :)

Answer (score 1):

This requirement is not possible in Snowflake, as access to securable objects is allowed via privileges assigned to roles, which are in turn assigned to users or other roles only.

Role is an entity to which privileges can be granted and the roles are in turn assigned to users. Roles can also be assigned to other roles, creating a role hierarchy.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-overview?utm_source=legacy&utm_medium=serp&utm_term=rbac#role-hierarchy-and-privilege-inheritance